# Search specific data from Google Log Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I want to export the log from Logs Explorer to the BigQuery using sink, so i can visualize the metric with Looker Studio, instead of Google Monitoring. I already move the data, but i don't know how to find the specific rows for visualize CPU/RAM/Disks.

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsjrI.png) is the visualization from the Google Monitoring that i want to duplicate in Looker, but i just knowing Log Explorer query like

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
resource.labels.zone="asia-southeast"
resource.labels.instance_id="123123123123123"
```

Is anyone know how to find the specific rows for that RAM/CPU/Disk or any references? Thank you